# initialise a C++ std::array of struct in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct

I've read the similar questions, but does anyone know why if I have a struct

```
struct ArabicRoman {
    char roman;
    int arabic;
};
```

I can initialise a C++ `std::array` in the following way:

```
ArabicRoman M({'M', 1000});
ArabicRoman D({'D', 500});
array<ArabicRoman, 2> const SYMBOLS({ M, D });
```

I can initialise a C-style array in the following way:

```
ArabicRoman const SYMBOLS[]({ {'M', 1000}, {'D', 500} });
```

However, the following is not compiling:

```
array<ArabicRoman, 2> const SYMBOLS({ {'M', 1000}, {'D', 500} });
```

any workaround to initialise C++ style arrays of structs?

Comment: You need more braces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to replaces parentheses with braces:

```
std::array<ArabicRoman, 2> const SYMBOLS {{ {'M', 1000}, {'D', 500} }};
                                         ^                           ^
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49e57279ec955020)

Comment: thanks! I saw now in the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array that this style of double brace initialisation is C++11 syntax, and won't be required any more in C++14

Comment: @stilvo It is true that you don't need double braces in simple cases, but with nested braces they can be hard to avoid...