# Why can't std::array<std::pair<int,int>, 3> be initialized using nested initializer lists, but std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> can?

Tags: c++, stdarray, aggregate-initialization

See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/5PqYWP

How come this array of pairs can't be initialized in the same way as a vector of pairs?

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>    v{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}; // succeeds 
    std::array <std::pair<int,int>, 3> a{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}; // fails to compile
}
```

Comment: A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65193350/10871073) was asked today, but with a `struct` instead of a `std::pair`. But the answer there is much the same as any here would be, IMHO. (Or maybe not - that one is about an assignment rather than a constructor?)

Comment: @AdrianMole _but with a `struct` instead of a `std::pair`_ I would expect that the [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is actually a (template) `struct`. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I can't disagree (even if I wanted to, which I don't).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add an outer pair of braces to initialize the `std::array<...>` object itself:

```
std::array <std::pair<int,int>, 3> a{{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};
```

The outermost pair is for the array object, the second pair is for the aggregate array inside the object. Then the list of elements in the array.

Comment: So why is `vector` different from `array`?

Comment: `std::array` is an aggregate, so you need `{}` to construct the `std::array` class, and a `{}` to construct it's member array.  `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`, so the `{}` to construct the vector automatically calls that.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, so it's actually two different mechanisms? An explicit constructor with vector, and a plain old aggregate initialization with array?

Comment: @MooingDuck Also: Could I aggregate-initialize a std::vector (which surely also is an aggregate)?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: No. an "Aggregate" is basically "a class whose members are all public and has no explicit constructors", which lets you directly construct the array member of the `std::array`.  Instead, `std::vector` has private members that you can't access yourself, and custom constructors, so it's not an aggregate.

Answer (score 14):

Specializations of the class template `std::array` represent aggregates that enclose another aggregate.

The reason of the error is that the first braced initializer in this declaration

```
std::array <std::pair<int,int>, 3> a{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
                                     ^^^^^
```

is considered as an initializer of the inner aggregate. In this case the following braced initializers are considered as redundant initializers.

So you can write either

```
std::array <std::pair<int, int>, 3> a{ { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} } };
                                       ^                   ^
                                       |the inner aggregate|
```

or like

```
std::array <std::pair<int, int>, 3> a{ std::make_pair( 1, 2 ), std::make_pair( 3, 4 ), std::make_pair( 5, 6 ) };
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that std::array doesn't have a initializer_list constructor, which vector does.

Comment: @iwans std::array is an aggregate. It does not have user declared constructors.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's too bad, isn't it?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I do not think so. This class (aggregate) simulates an array that in turn is an aggregate.